# Python argparse - optional argument 'overriding' required one

Tags: python, argparse

I'm looking for a way to have the following behavior with argparse.

Imagine as an example that I want a program that pretty print a file given as input.
And I also want an optional argument to display the list of file types that the program handles.
What I'd like is the following behavior.

```bash
myparser ./myfile.json
```

> this would pretty print the file `myfile.json`

```bash
myparser --list
```

> this would display the list of handled file types

However, I don't see how to do it: in the second line, argparse asks me to provide the `filepath` argument.

So I could either do what I want by doing `myparser . --list` and code the program such that the `filepath` argument is ignored when the list argument is provided.

Or I could set the `filepath` argument as optional, which would require me to do the following:

`myparser --filepath ./myfile.json`

Both solutions work fine, but I'm still curious about if it is possible to have the behavior that I want. Do you have any solution ? (Remark that the behavior that I'm looking for is exactly the one of the `help` argument)

Comment: Unless you explicitly told argparse that `--list` is a bare flag, where's the actual *argument* for the `--list` flag? Also known as: show the argparse code you wrote. It's doing exactly what you told it to do, so [show what you told it to do](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think the issue is that with `--list`, `myparser` still expects the required filename argument.

Comment: Exactly, hence the request for their actual code that sets up argparse to be included into the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just for contrast, you need to make the file name optional. That means providing an explicit `--print` option instead of a required file name, so that your usage is either

```
myparser --print ./myfile.json
```

or

```
myparser --list
```

Closer to what you *actually* want is to define a custom action that exits your script early, much like `version` or `help`.

```
class ListAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest=argparse.SUPPRESS, default=argparse.SUPPRESS, help=None):
        super().__init__(option_strings=option_strings, nargs=0, dest=dest, default=default, help=help)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        print("Hello world")
        parser.exit()

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('name')
p.add_argument('--list', action=ListAction)
```

Now `myparser --list` will process `--list` and exit before it notices that the required filename option is missing.

(The definition of `ListAction` is modeled explicitly after the definition of [`argparse._HelpAction`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/argparse.py#L1104).)

Comment: A positional with `nargs='?'` might be enough.

Comment: That's fragile once you start having more than one positional argument. Stick with solutions that have clear semantics, rather than playing around with syntax that makes some corner cases work at the expense of others.

Comment: But that's certainly *a* solution and possibly worth posting, if you like.